# LEFT JOIN removes rows that are not present on the right table

Tags: sql

I'm trying to merge/join two tables.

TABLE1 (left) is the main table I am trying to join on, it contains:

- strings that are in TABLE2;
- strings that are not in TABLE2;
- null values (normal in my case and would like them to be kept)

I use the following command:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1 
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.UNIQUE_ID = TABLE2.UNIQUE_ID_OF_CUSTOMERS
```

The issue is that it drops all the rows that are not in TABLE2 and does a form of a weird join that I cannot understand how to fix

Comment: Why have you tagged two different RDBMS platforms? MySql <> Sql Server

Comment: A `LEFT JOIN` will not cause any rows in the first table to not be returned, unless you've done something like turned the `LEFT JOIN` into an implicit `INNER JOIN` in the `WHERE`.

Comment: @Stu Fixed, mb
@Larnu I have set up certain conditions after for the TABLE2 with `WHERE TABLE2.AGE>40`

Comment: That's likely not the full query and you have in your `WHERE` clause `TABLE2.SOMEFIELD = SOMEVAL`. If you only want to `LEFT JOIN` the records from `TABLE2` that meet a specific criteria, add it as an `AND` to your `JOIN`.

Comment: Move any filters on `Table2` from your `WHERE` clause into your `ON` clause and rerun. You want to filter those records BEFORE the join in the `ON` clause, not AFTER the join in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: `WHERE TABLE2.AGE>40` good to know my crystal ball is still working; that is an implicit `INNER JOIN`. `TABLE2.AGE` cannot have a value greater than 40 if no row was found (and thus the value of the column is `NULL`). That clause should b in the `ON` *not* the `WHERE`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one will only return rows where AGE > 40, so a NULL will not be true. The second one moves the filter to the ON clause, so you will get rows where TABLE2 row is null.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1 
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.UNIQUE_ID = TABLE2.UNIQUE_ID_OF_CUSTOMERS
WHERE TABLE2.AGE > 40


SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1 
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.UNIQUE_ID = TABLE2.UNIQUE_ID_OF_CUSTOMERS
                AND TABLE2.AGE > 40
```

Comment: Worked, it was an issue that I stated `WHERE` instead of `AND`

Comment: It's not that it was `WHERE` instead of `AND`, @AkmalSoliev , but that the clause should have been in the `ON`. `AND` isn't a replacement of `WHERE` here, the clause you had in the `WHERE` has been moved to be part of the `ON` instead. If you had other clauses in the `WHERE` (against `TABLE1`), simply changing the `WHERE` to an `AND` would have given *vastly* different behaviour.